# Input/output format for Fine Tuning Huggingface RobertaForQuestionAnswering

Tags: nlp, huggingface-transformers, bert-language-model, nlp-question-answering, roberta-language-model

I'm trying to fine-tune "RobertaForQuestionAnswering" on my custom dataset and I'm confused about the input params it takes. Here's the sample code.

```
>>> from transformers import RobertaTokenizer, RobertaForQuestionAnswering
>>> import torch

>>> tokenizer = RobertaTokenizer.from_pretrained('roberta-base')
>>> model = RobertaForQuestionAnswering.from_pretrained('roberta-base')

>>> question, text = "Who was Jim Henson?", "Jim Henson was a nice puppet"
>>> inputs = tokenizer(question, text, return_tensors='pt')
>>> start_positions = torch.tensor([1])
>>> end_positions = torch.tensor([3])

>>> outputs = model(**inputs, start_positions=start_positions, end_positions=end_positions)
>>> loss = outputs.loss
>>> start_scores = outputs.start_logits
>>> end_scores = outputs.end_logits
```

I'm not able to understand variables **start_positions** & **end_positions** which are being given in the model as input and variables **start_scores** & **end_scores** that are being generated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Question Answering ot is basically a DL model that creates an answer by *extracting part of the context* (in you case what is called `text`). This means that the goal of the QAbot is to identify the **start** and the **end** of the answer.

---

Basic functioning of a QAbot:

First of all, every word of the question and context is tokenized. This means it is (possibily divided into characters/subwords and then) convertend into a number. It really depends on the type of tokenizer (which means it depends on the model you are using, since you will be using the same tokenizer - it's what the third line of your code is doing). I suggest [this very useful guide](https://huggingface.co/course/chapter2/4?fw=pt).

Then, the tokenized `question + text` are passed into the model which performs its internal operations. Remember when I told at the beginning that the model will identify the `start` and the `end` of the answer? Well, it does so by calculating for every token of the `question + text` the probability that that particular token is the start of the answer. This probabilities are the softmaxed version of the `start_logits`. After that, the same operations are performed for the end token.

So, this is what `start_scores` and `end_scores` are: the pre-softmax scores that every token is start and end of the answer, respectively.

---

So, what are `start_position` and `stop_position`?

As stated [here](https://huggingface.co/transformers/model_doc/roberta.html#robertaforquestionanswering), they are:

> `start_positions` (`torch`.`LongTensor` of shape (`batch_size`,), optional) –
> Labels for position (index) of the start of the labelled span for
> computing the token classification loss. Positions are clamped to the
> length of the sequence (`sequence_length`). Position outside of the
> sequence are not taken into account for computing the loss.
>
> `end_positions` (`torch`.`LongTensor` of shape (`batch_size`,), optional) –
> Labels for position (index) of the end of the labelled span for
> computing the token classification loss. Positions are clamped to the
> length of the sequence (`sequence_length`). Position outside of the
> sequence are not taken into account for computing the loss.

---

Moreover, the model you are using (`roberta-base`, see [the model on the HuggingFace repository](https://huggingface.co/roberta-base) and the [RoBERTa official paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1907.11692)) has **NOT** been fine-tuned for QuestionAnswering. It is "just" a model trained by using MaskedLanguageModeling, which means that the model has a general understanding of the english language, but it is not suitable for question asnwering. You can use it of course, but it would probably give non optimal results.

I suggest you use the same model, inthe version specifically fine-tuned on QuestionAnswering: `roberta-base-squad2`, see [it on HuggingFace](https://huggingface.co/deepset/roberta-base-squad2?context=Jim%20Henson%20was%20a%20nice%20puppet&question=Who%20was%20Jim%20Henson%3F).

In practical terms, you have to replace the lines where you load the model and the tokenizer with:

```
tokenizer = RobertaTokenizer.from_pretrained('roberta-base-squad2')
model = RobertaForQuestionAnswering.from_pretrained('roberta-base-squad2')
```

This will give much more accurate results.

Bonus read: [what fine-tuning is and how it works](https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2020/07/transfer-learning-for-nlp-fine-tuning-bert-for-text-classification/)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I just have one doubt, does it matter how we assign variables `start_positions` and `start_positions`? what's their role in the whole process?

Comment: @tarangranpara I updated my answer with firther details

Comment: Thank you so much @SilentCloud. It really helped, I appreciate your efforts!